# How Can write proguard rules for dialogflow in android application?

Tags: android, dialogflow-es, proguard

I am integrated Dialogflow in my android application. its working in debug mode. When i take the release apk file. But chat bot not working. the reason proguard is not enable for dialog flow. How can write the proguard for dialogflow.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this in your proguard rules:

```
-keep public class com.google.api.gax.core.* { public protected *; }
-keep public class com.google.auth.oauth2.* { public protected *; }
```